# How to read a very large text file (~15GB)?

Tags: r, csv, large-data, large-files

I have a very large .txt file which I need to load into RStudio. The file contains ~850,000 Columns and ~2000 rows. Too large to open in Excel to convert to .csv. A description of the txt file contents:

SampleID,CpGprobeID1,CpGprobeID2(x850K)...
ID1,betavalue1(x850k)
ID2,betavalue1(x850K)...

Of this .txt file, I actually only need ~30000 of the columns (CpGprobeIDs). I have a .csv file containing those 30000 required CpGprobeIDs, listed in rows rather than columns (call this file CpGprobeIDsREDUCED.csv)

**Is there a way that I can reduce the columns in the 15GB .txt file to only containing the ID's from the ~30000 rows CpGprobeIDsREDUCED.csv, or another way to load such a large file into RStudio?**

So far I have unsucessfully tried:

```
library(data.table)
filename <- fread("filename.txt")
```

^ R encounters a fatal error and the session aborts. This actually does work for a smaller sample size of ~24 rows, even with the 850K columns, so this is the closest I got.

So then I tried converting it to a csv file containing only the ~30000 required IDs and encountered the following error message:

```
library(readr)
CpGprobeIDsREDUCED <- read_csv("CpGprobeIDsREDUCED.csv")
library(sqldf)
CpGkeep <- CpGprobeIDsREDUCED$Name
import_filename <- fn$read.csv.sql("filename.txt",  sep="\t", sql = "select * from file where 
SampleID in ( `toString(CpGkeep)` )")

Error: too many columns on file
In addition: Warning message:
In for (i in seq_along(col)) col[i] <- length(scan(file, what = "", :
closing unused connection 3 (filename.txt)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do next, any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use a real programming language (or awk) to preprocess/trim the CSV file.

Comment: Have you tried `fread` with the `select` argument which allows you to read only the columns in `CpGprobeIDsREDUCED$Name` so that would become `fread("filename.txt", select = CpGprobeIDsREDUCED$Name)`

Comment: @wildplasser to understand why this comment isn't helpful replace `R` with `SQL`.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg, thanks for your response. Yes unfortunately this causes the same fatal error as the fread function.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know any SQL implementation that would allow even 30000 columns, so in that case preprocessing would be needed. [been there]

Comment: It might be worth giving `read_csv` from `readr` a try. It allows you to select the columns you would like to read before reading the full file through the `col_select` argument.

Comment: read your file chunk by chunk:
- use a file connection (cf `?file`)
- first read the header
- then in a loop: 
   - read chunk
   - subset it with CpGprobeIDsREDUCED and save it in a lst
- at the end, rbind_all your subsets from lst into a data frame

Answer (score 2):

This is where e.g. `disk.frame` may be used, but there are a few other options out there.

Setup your frame with

```r
setup_disk.frame()
options(future.globals.maxSize = Inf)
```

Then load your data with

```r
df_path = file.path(tempdir(), "tmp.df")

data <- csv_to_disk.frame(
  "filename.txt", 
  outdir = df_path,
  overwrite = T)
```

Also check out this example from [their vignette](https://diskframe.com/articles/intro-disk-frame.html)

> If the CSV is too large to read in, then we can also use the in_chunk_size option to control how many rows to read in at once. For example to read in the data 100,000 rows at a time.

```r
library(nycflights13)
library(disk.frame)

# write a csv
csv_path = file.path(tempdir(), "tmp_flights.csv")

data.table::fwrite(flights, csv_path)

df_path = file.path(tempdir(), "tmp_flights.df")

flights.df <- csv_to_disk.frame(
  csv_path, 
  outdir = df_path, 
  in_chunk_size = 100000)
  
flights.df
```

Comment: thanks! Loading the .txt file with in_chunk_size seemed to be working (I tried with very small chunks of 24), but the problem then came when appending the disk frames: 
Error: Can't combine `..1$cg12976667` <double> and `..2$cg12976667` <character>...

Comment: Have you tried increasing the chunk size?